# Throttling Android WiFi Traffic

Tags: android, wifi, bandwidth, throttling, bandwidth-throttling

Does anyone know how this can be done? If so - has anyone seen any examples, tutorials or repositories containing such a method?

I've found the following:

http://dinote.wordpress.com/opens-asynchronous-android-httprequest/

But I'd like to throttle all traffic - not just one HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do you testing on an emulator, then you can change the data latency by going to your Run Configuration -> Target and then scrolling down to see the respective setting (in Eclipse). If it has to be on a real device, or has to be purely through wifi, then what I said is not relevant.

HTH,
Ali.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which can be integrated into my source code  for implementation in actual devices. 

(Thank you for your input though!)